# Should use Android tabhost or android action bar tabs based on requirement

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I have recently started on android application development and developing my first app. I want to develop a tab based interface. I don't need to use compatibility lib. for older versions.

I want to have interface like this:

[image]

I know that tabbed activity is something which is something deprecated. So now I am left with two options I know. Actionbar tabs (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) or tab host with tab widget as shown in example here: http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-tabs-with-fragments/

At the end of this article, I read that this way is outdated and action bar tabs is recommended way. But in my case other than tabs  I have two requirements:

1. I need another common area in activity rather than those tabs. I am not sure if action bar tabs way i can have that common area as well. Area in image with edittext is place, i am talking about.
2. I need to communicate between two tabs and parent activity.

So my question is that which way I should work? Tab host with tab widgets or action bar tabs. Or I am thinking wrong and there is some other better way I can achieve this thing. This common area will be sort of log area, where different actions will be inserted and it will be scrolled downward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't need to use compatibility lib. for older versions

The Android Support library has many, many things that are not "for older versions". Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html):

> The Android Support Library package is a set of code libraries that provide backward-compatible versions of Android framework APIs as well as features that are only available through the library APIs.

This has been the case for about four years.

> I know that tabbed activity is something which is something depreciated

Action bar tabs were also deprecated, as of last year and the Android 5.0 release.

> So my question is that which way I should work? Tab host with tab widgets or action bar tabs.

Probably neither. Use `TabLayout`, `FragmentTabHost`, or any of [the many third-party libraries that add tabs to a `ViewPager`](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111).

Of the two that you cite, `TabHost` with views for tabs is the only currently supported approach.

Comment: For FragmentTabHost usage, is it necessary to use FragmentActvity from v4 suppot library as both of them are from v4 support library?

Comment: @Hafiz: There are two `FragmentTabHost` classes. The `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` works with `FragmentActivity` and the fragment backport. `android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost` is found in the `support-v13` library, and it works with `Activity` and the native fragment implementation.

Comment: Which one should I use? Both work same way except the difference that in one I will need to use FragmentActivity ?

Comment: @Hafiz: "Which one should I use?" -- I have no way to answer that. "Both work same way except the difference that in one I will need to use FragmentActivity ?" -- yes, along with the rest of the fragment backport. Note that if you are using `appcompat-v7` (e.g., `AppCompatActivity`), it inherits from `FragmentActivity`.